# Setting width of figure element in fbox / minipage

Tags: captions, minipage, fbox

Following code is currently used to show a figure:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \lineskip=-\fboxrule
  \fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
  \end{minipage}}
  \fbox{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
    \caption{The caption text}
  \end{minipage}}
  \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Image with caption]

Question: How can I adjust the code so that the full box is only 0.5\textwidth of a page, with the image being full width *within* the box?

Comment: what is the intention of `\lineskip=-\fboxrule` ? (the behaviour with negative lineskip is defined but rather odd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\lineskip=-\fboxrule
\fbox{\parbox{0.5\linewidth}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}}\\ \fbox{\parbox{0.5\linewidth}{
    \caption{The caption text}
    \label{fig:test}
                        }}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**addedndum:**
if you have many such figures, than it might be sensible to define new command as:

```
\newcommand\fparbox[2]{\fbox{\parbox{#1}{#2}}}
```

and than use it as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\newcommand\fparbox[2]{\fbox{\parbox{#1}{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\lineskip=-\fboxrule
\fparbox{0.5\linewidth}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}\\    
\fparbox{0.5\linewidth}{
    \caption{The caption text}
    \label{fig:test}
                        }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

result is the same as before.

Answer (score 3):

You are artificially enlarging the box by placing the image within a minipage. If you want the box to have the same width as your image, just remove the minipage:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
  \lineskip=-\fboxrule
  \fbox{%
%  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
%    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}%
%  \end{minipage}
  }%

  \fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}
    \caption{The caption text}
  \end{minipage}
  }
  \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works for the image and it's frame but the caption is still full width? Both should only be 50% of the full page.

Comment: @TensorJoe But if the caption is longer it will occupy the whole textwidth, so it would leak out of a 50% width box. Is this intended?

Comment: No, actually the solution above worked well. Yet, I appreciate your help and upvoted. Thank you!